# Vídeo expansivo via efeito de hover

Tags: html, css

Tenho um cliente que ele quer colocar uma publicidade em forma de vídeo e quando o usuário passa o mouse por cima desse vídeo ele expande na tela e começa a rodar. Procurei em todo canto e não achei nada, pensei em fazer isso via transition e animation pelo css e trazer o video via iframe, mas queria saber se existe alguma forma mais correta de fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente aumentar o tamanho da div ao receber o hover, porém será necessário utilizar um pouco de javascript.

Exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/tdsNF/1/